# karate 1.3.1 feature files containing javascript functions

Tags: karate

I have feature files containing defined javascript functions that call Karate UI functions, e.g., waitFor, print, click, and others. These have been working fine until I upgraded to Karate 1.3.1. In that version, those karate UI functions are not found. I am using java 11 and I didn't see a mention of this change in the upgrade notes. Am I missing something?
thanks
Chris

Comment: can you try 1.4.0.RC3 - if you still see issues, it is very important that you provide a way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2224 - also please see this since you mentioned UI: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1280